# onClick Div Appears for seconds and then it disappears

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to hide a div when the page loads. So I added a class hidden to my html row as mentioned below.

```
<div class="row hidden" id="printdiv">
    //Row data goes here
</div>
```

It is working perfectly and hides the row when I load my application in browser.

Now I want to show the div when user click the `order` button

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary save" name="save" value="Order">
```

My jQuery Code for showing the div is

```
$(".save").click(function() {
    $('#printdiv').removeClass('hidden');
    $('#printdiv').addClass('show');
});
```

Now when I load my application in the browser and I click on the order button it shows the div just for 1 or 2 seconds and then the div disappears. I want the div to be there when the order button is clicked. How can I make that div appears to be there for permanent use ?

Comment: change `type="submit" ` to `type="button" `

Comment: Or `e.preventDefault()`

Comment: when do you want to submit the form?

Comment: @guradio but I also want to submit data to server with that button therefore type is submit . In simple words I want that button to submit data and also show the div bcz the result will come to that div.

Comment: then do what @RayonDabre suggested then after you done what you want do manual submit `$('form').submit();`

Comment: something like `$(".save").click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault()
    $('#printdiv').removeClass('hidden');
    $('#printdiv').addClass('show');
$('form').submit();
});`

Comment: @guradio, __No__, Some delay must be needed!

Comment: still not working its like flash and goes back!

Comment: @LaravelWarrior you page must be getting reloaded.. because of the form submit. place a alert on document ready and check...

Comment: Yes it does refreshes but is there any way to perform a submit and get the results clean bcz I also want to submit data to server with that button therefore type is submit . In simple words I want that button to submit data and also show the div bcz the result will come to that div

Comment: I have tried it in my snippet but I am not able to get the problem. you asked in this question

Comment: use ajax - that is the only way to submit and retrieve information from the server without reloading your page!

Comment: Share your full code, it might be helpful..

Answer (score 4):

If you are submitting data to the server then you must add show class from your server side.

something like this in php

```
echo "<script>$('#printdiv').removeClass('hidden');$('#printdiv').addClass('show');</script>"
```

Comment: This helped me (y)

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be working for me, please edit my code to explain the problem.

```js
$(".save").click(function() {
    $('#printdiv').removeClass('hidden');
    $('#printdiv').addClass('show');
});
```

```css
.hidden{
  display : none;  
}

.show{
  display : block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row hidden" id="printdiv">
//it shows
</div>


<form action="">
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname" value="Mickey"><br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Mouse"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary save" name="save" value="Order">
</form>
```

Comment: I don't know why but in my case the div which I want to show just appears for 1 sec and then it hides .

Comment: do you have a link , i can debug and see

Comment: no I am working on localhost. Is there any way to contact you ?

Comment: What is the value for this -- `<form action="">` in your code. Add your complete form code in question. it might help

Comment: I am using Laravel for backend and it's action = "{{ url('/orders') }}"

Answer (score 1):

If you are expecting the result to be loaded in that div, you should change the input to button, submit the data with an AJAX post, then load the response in that div and show it in the success callback. Otherwise, you need to handle the visibility of the div server side before you return the response.

Comment: how to handle it on server side?

Comment: That depends on what back end technology you are using, the best approach in my opinion is to post the data using AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to show the data returned from the server in the div you'll have to wait for the server response and then show your div. You can use ajax for that, getting rid of the annoying page reload. a jquery function for that is

```
$.post('yourPHPfile.php, {data:data}, function(data){
     $("#printdiv").html(data).show();
})
```

where `{data:data},` - the first `data` is the name of the post variable, the second `data` is it's value http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Comment: I did but still it appears for just 1 seconds and then it goes back.

Comment: @LaravelWarrior : please check my answer

Answer (score 0):

Remove the hide class from the row class div. And apply the jquery

```
<div class="row" id="printdiv">
    //Row data goes here
</div>
```

// Jquery Code

```
$('#printdiv').hide(0);

$(".save").click(function() {
    $('#printdiv').show(500);
});
```

Comment: It also just appears for seconds and then it goes back!

Comment: can you share your code of chunk. Then we can help you

Answer (score 0):

Just change your button type from 'submit' to 'button' and use below code.

```
 $('#printdiv').attr("class","row show");
```

No need to write below mentioned two lines.

```
 $('#printdiv').removeClass('hidden');
 $('#printdiv').addClass('show');
```

Comment: Changin to button won't work for submitting data bcz I also want to submit data to server with that button therefore type is submit . In simple words I want that button to submit data and also show the div bcz the result will come to that div

Comment: Its not a big deal we can submit a form using Jquery .submit() method, just use this code at the end of function body.     $("#formId").submit();

Comment: replace formId with your form tag Id

Answer (score -1):

Check below code, it may help you.

```js
    $(".save").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#printdiv').toggleClass("hidden");
});
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <form action="#">
  <div class="row hidden" id="printdiv">
    //Row data goes here
  </div>
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary save" name="save" value="Order">
</form>
```

Comment: you got rid of the form, that's why it doesn't get submitted, but the OP needs the form for the functionality he desires

Comment: here also you can use preventDefault(); to avoid the same